# angularjs-nvd3-directives value outside function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, nvd3.js

I can't find a way to retrieve a value from a function of angular-nvd3-directives, I tried everything, using `$emit`, `$broadcast`, `$scope.varName`. 
I have the correct value printend in console, but I can't access it in the template.

I hope someone can help me, here's the code

in the controller:

```
$scope.keyName="start"; // this works

$scope.$on("keyName", function(event, mass){
   $scope.keyName = mass; //correctly assigned as printed in console
   console.log( $scope.keyName); 
   console.log(event.currentScope); // here I find everything inside the scope 
                                    // I'm successuffly using elsewhere in the code
});

$scope.toolTipContentFunction = function(){
  return function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
     $scope.$broadcast("keyName", key);//this correctly broadcast (or emit) the value
     return  'Super New Tooltip' +
      '<h1>' + key + '</h1>' +
        '<p>' +  y + ' at ' + x + '</p>'
  }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div>
<!-- {{exampleData}} -->
<nvd3-pie-chart
  data="exampleData"
  id="colorExample"
  width="550"
  height="350"
  x="xFunction()"
  y="yFunction()"
  toolTips="true"
  objectequality="false"
  tooltipcontent="toolTipContentFunction()">
  {{keyName}}
  <svg height="250"></svg>
</nvd3-pie-chart>
</div>
```

exampleData is rendered, keyName is not.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it. I'm a beginner.

I had to apply the change to the variable, like that:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.keyName = mass;
});
```

so now the function is:

```
$scope.$on("keyName", function(event, mass){
   $scope.$apply(function(){
     $scope.keyName = mass;
   });      
 });
```

Here's the illuminating article: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Answer (score 0):

You can put `{{keyName}}` outside `nvd3-pie-chart`. It doesn't have any differences.